# Jenkins keeps changing my workspace path

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I created a new project in Jenkins and when configuring made sure to uncheck the 'Let Jenkins Create Workspace' and 'Let Jenkins Manage Workspace View' boxes because I didn't want Jenkins to change my default workspace path (C:\workspace). However once a build was triggered it automatically changed the workspace path to C:\tools\Jenkins\jobs\project_name\workspace. Changing the path is unacceptable because a lot of my source files are dependent on the C:\workspace path.

Am I misunderstanding the function of the boxes I unchecked? How do I keep my path at C:\workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used Perforce Plugin and I don't know what these checkboxes do.  But normally if you want to fix workspace's path you can use `Configure->Advanced Project Options->Use custom workspace` checkbox. As described in documentation it does what you need:

> Normally you should let Jenkins allocate and clean up workspace directories, but in several situations this is problematic, and in such case, this option lets you specify the workspace location manually.
>   One such situation is where paths are hard-coded and the code needs to be built on a specific location. While there's no doubt that such a build is not ideal, this option allows you to get going in such a situation.

Maybe you have to play also  with 'Let Jenkins Create Workspace' and 'Let Jenkins Manage Workspace View' checkboxes.